# Is this way to combine two functions into a new function called a function product?

Tags: sets, functional-programming

I have been looking for a maths operation that allows me to combine functions in a specific way. For example if we have functions f and g both with single mappings from o to e and v to c respectively, and we want to achieve whats below.

f ? g =  {o -> e} ? {v -> c} = {(o,v) -> (e,c)}

I have been told that what I'm looking for is called a function product. I can't find anything about this, also does it have a another name?

I've been told this is how to compute it, where X is called the function product.

(f X g)(x,u) = (f(x), g(u))

Which works, but I cant find anything about it online.

Answer (score 1):

This operation is known as [the cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) for functions. This product is not limited only to functions, but can *usually* be applied to almost every mathematical object.

But the "usual" notion of "function product" is referring to [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition), which is a totally different thing. It is calculated like that:
$$(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$$
While the cartesian product is calculated like that:
$$(f\times g)(x,y) = (f(x),g(y))$$

Comment: Do you know where I could find the proof for cartesian product of functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "proof"? this is the *definition* of the cartesian product of functions

Comment: I see, it is an axiom, but then why was it chosen? How does it fit in with cartesian products of other things?